# To insert images as embed ones by default

Tags: adobe-indesign, images

I often work with a large number of small images, so I would prefer them to be embed rather than linked. Is it possible to tell InDesign to insert images as embed ones **by default**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to have InDesign embed images by default as you place them. You can, however, select all of the linked images in the 'links' palette and then use the links palette menu to embed them all with one click, which is almost as easy.

Generally speaking, it is not recommended best practise to embed all of your images. It makes for a large InDesign file and takes away the ability to auto update images that have been edited. If keeping track of lots of images from different locations is your issue, then I would recommend using the File>Package function to gather all of your linked images into one folder.